# How can I disable the history in `xclipboard`?

Tags: linux, x11, clipboard, x

If I run `xclipboard` to keep a persistent `CLIPBOARD`, there is automatically a history created of all the content which was in the `CLIPBOARD` at some time.

[image]

How can I disable the history?

Comment: Modify the source.

Comment: as you said....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for xclipboard](https://github.com/mig/openbsd-xenocara/blob/master/app/xclipboard/xclipboard.c) it has no such capability. So you cannot disable the history through any normal means provided by this tool. Your options are to use an alternative (there are many) or modify its source.

Alternative clipboarding apps:

- [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon): Integrates well with Unity and GNOME, including a nice indicator applet
- [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ): An advanced clipboard manager that is also cross platform
- [GPaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste): GTK+ 3 based and integrates well with GNOME
- [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper): A good choice for KDE users
- [Clipman](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-clipman-plugin): A lightweight option for those who prefer XFCE
- [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/): A simple "basic-features only" option for those who like simplicity

There are others, this is just a partial list to get you started.

#### References

- [6 Linux clipboard managers to boost your productivity](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/clipboard-managers)